# Making a Cursor run

Tags: android

This is almost certainly a really stupid question but I am struggling with working out the answer.

I have got all my database code ready to go, but it's not working for some reason. I've set up some tests to debug it in my Cursor, but none of them are showing up - even the Toast isn't working. This has led me to conclude that the Cursor class itself isn't running. The code I have currently is:

```
    public Cursor getDatabase(String category) 
    {
    String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    myData = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY); 

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String cat = intent.getExtras().getString("category");

    Cursor cur;
    cur=myData.rawQuery("select * from youthcentres where cat1='Arts'",null);
    cur.moveToFirst();

    final int fault = cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow("name");

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), fault, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    String name = cur.getString(3);
    TextView centres = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.centres);
    centres.setText(name);

    TextView test = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.test);
    test.setText(fault);

    getDatabase(cat);

    myData.close();
    return cur;
    }
```

This is nestled within my `public class Display extends Activity`, as in:

```
public class Display extends Activity {
    public Cursor getDatabase(String category) {
        // etc
    }
}
```

Could anyone help me troubleshoot what's going on?

Comment: Where are you calling `getDatabase()`?

Comment: At the bottom, in getDatabase(cat). If I call it outside of this section, it throws up an error.

Comment: "At the bottom" of what? Please post the code where you are calling `getDatabase()`.

Comment: The code is already posted. At the bottom of the big chunk I quoted - it is within the `Cursor` class.

Comment: What is that: `final int fault = cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow("What is going on");`? A column named `"What is going on"`? Could you add a stack trace of the error/exception?

Comment: Edited: it should be cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow("name"), looking for "name".

Comment: Your code looks fine. I would start to investigate if your method is being called at all.